# What is the absolute significance of const?

Tags: ecmascript-6, constants

So I'd just like some clarification so I know what we're really doing here. I'm learning about the 'const' function in es6 and I'm not really sure how it's changing anything.

First, if I define a variable with const and later assign a new value to it with var, the whole thing crashes. Here's what I mean

```
<script>
const x = 10;
var  x = 10;
// x doesn't get any value assigned
</script>
```

Second if I define a universal variable with var and later on define a local variable with const (which i could have equally done with var or let), it works only within that function where the local variable gets defined with const but outside the function, it's still the old value that i defined with var. Here's what I mean

```
<script>
var  x = 10;
  // Here x is 10
{  
const x = 2;
  // Here x is 2
}
// Here x is 10
</script>
```

So what real difference is 'const' making then? or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: `const` indicates that it is a constant and its value cannot be reassigned. It can be useful to cache DOM nodes, for example, since you're never going to mutate the collection anyway. And your second point, that is the beauty of const. It's scoped not only within functions, but also within if/else or for loops, for example. So you're not afraid of overwriting function-scoped variables.

Comment: I'm glad you think const is a hot girl, but my point is that so far, I've observed that where ever you can use const, 'let' and 'var' are probably better options

Comment: Not necessarily. `let` has the same scope restrictions as `const` but allows reassignment. So if you're using `let` on a variable that does not need to be reassigned, use `const`. Use of `const` explicitly tells you (the coder) and the browser that the variable cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it’s a good idea to stop using `var` if you are writing ES6. Simply use `const` for constants and `let` for variables.

The first example crashes because you are redefining a `const` **which is already defined** in that scope. Same thing would happen when redefining a `let` variable. I know var allows redefining, but this makes the code hard to read.

The second example works as expected because you are defining the constant in a new scope. The example bellow would also work.

```
<script>
const x = 10;
{  
  const x = 2;
}
</script>
```

**Bottom line**: you can't redefine variables [`let`] and constants [`constants`] in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more scoped related rather than const/var.

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.

More here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: if you're going to change the value it holds, doesn't it mean you're reassigning the variable identifier? it's the same thing right?

Comment: No. For instance I can add property to the const object, but I can't  link the identifier to a new object.